# Custom exception handling in Java, how do I only print out my argument in exception object without calling the a outside class?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Here's a code for a TriangleExtra class. It constructs triangle with 3 sides (written on Java):

```
public class TriangleExtra extends SimpleGeometricObject {
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;
    private static int numberOfObjects;

    //Constructor 1
    public TriangleExtra() throws IllegalTriangleException {
        super("Yellow", false);
        numberOfObjects += 1;
        try {
            checkLegality(1, 1, 1);
            setSide1(1);
            setSide2(1);
            setSide3(1);
        } catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    } // end constructor 1

    //Constructor 2
    public TriangleExtra(double side) throws IllegalTriangleException {
        super("Blue", true);
        numberOfObjects += 1;
        try {
            checkLegality(side, side, side);    
            setSide1(side);
            setSide2(side);
            setSide3(side);
        } catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    } // end contructor 2

    //Contructor 3
    public TriangleExtra(double side1, double side2, double side3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
        super("Red", false);
        numberOfObjects += 1;
        try {
            checkLegality(side1, side2, side3); 
            setSide1(side1);
            setSide2(side2);
            setSide3(side3);
        } catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    } // end constructor 3

    //Check if it's valid triangle
    public boolean checkLegality (double side1, double side2, double side3) 
            throws IllegalTriangleException {
        boolean testSides = (side3 + side2 > side1) & 
                (side1 > Math.abs(side3 - side2));
        boolean testPositive = (side1 > 0 & side2 > 0 & side3 > 0);
        if (testSides & testPositive)
            return true;
        else
            throw new IllegalTriangleException(side1, side2, side3);
    } // end checkLegality

    //Get side methods
    public double getSide1() {
        return this.side1;
    }
    public double getSide2() {
        return this.side2;
    }
    public double getSide3() {
        return this.side3;
    }  // end get sides

    //Set side methods
    private void setSide1(double side1) {
        this.side1 = side1;
    }
    private void setSide2(double side2) {
        this.side2 = side2;
    }
    private void setSide3(double side3) {
        this.side3 = side3;
    } // end set sides

    //get area
    public double getArea() {
        double s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
        double area = Math.sqrt(s*(s-side1)*(s-side2)*(s-side3));
        return area;
    } // end get Area

    // get perimeter
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return side1 + side2 + side3;
    } // end get Perimeter

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return (this.getSide1() == ((Triangle)other).getSide1() &
                this.getSide2() == ((Triangle)other).getSide2() &
                this.getSide3() == ((Triangle)other).getSide3());
    } // end equal()

    //get nr of objects (eve if invalid)
    public static int getNrOfObjects() {
        return numberOfObjects;
    }

    //to string
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = isFilled() ? "yes": "no";
        return "Sides: " + side1 + " " + side2 + " " + side3 +
                "\nBuilt on " + getDateBuilt() + "\ncolor: " + 
                getColor() + "\nFilled: " + s;
    } // end toString

}
```

And this is the IllegalTriangleException that the class above uses in its checkLegality method:

```
public class IllegalTriangleException extends Exception {
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;

    public IllegalTriangleException (double side1, 
            double side2, double side3) {
        super("Invalid triangle with sides " + side1 + " "
                + side2 + " and " + side3);
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
    }
}
```

And this is another class where I test run the TriangleExtra object:

```
public class TriangleExtraTry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TriangleExtra tr1 = new TriangleExtra(5);
            tr1.checkLegality(5, -1, 5);
            TriangleExtra tr2 = new TriangleExtra(1000, 1, 1);
            TriangleExtra tr3 = new TriangleExtra(-5, 5, 5);
            TriangleExtra tr4 = new TriangleExtra(0, 5, 4);

        }   catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);

        } 

          System.out.println("Number of objects constructed: " +
            TriangleExtra.getNrOfObjects());
        }
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides 1000.0 1.0 and 1.0
    at TriangleExtra.checkLegality(TriangleExtra.java:63)
    at TriangleExtra.<init>(TriangleExtra.java:44)
    at TriangleExtraTry.main(TriangleExtraTry.java:7)
IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides -5.0 5.0 and 5.0
    at TriangleExtra.checkLegality(TriangleExtra.java:63)
    at TriangleExtra.<init>(TriangleExtra.java:44)
    at TriangleExtraTry.main(TriangleExtraTry.java:8)
IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides 0.0 5.0 and 4.0
    at TriangleExtra.checkLegality(TriangleExtra.java:63)
    at TriangleExtra.<init>(TriangleExtra.java:44)
    at TriangleExtraTry.main(TriangleExtraTry.java:9)
IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides 5.0 -1.0 and 5.0
Number of objects constructed: 4
```

When I remove the line `tr1.checkLegality(5, -1, 5);` from the code above AND put off "throws IllegalTriangleException" from the constructor methods on TriangleExtra, it doesn't work, it just  says "Unreachable catch block for IllegalTriangleException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body". If I remove only `tr1.checkLegality(5, -1, 5);` then it doesn't write the last line `IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides 5.0 -1.0 and 5.0`

When I write this:

```
public class TriangleExtraTry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TriangleExtra tr1 = new TriangleExtra(5);
            TriangleExtra tr2 = new TriangleExtra(1000, 1, 1);
            TriangleExtra tr3 = new TriangleExtra(-5, 5, 5);
            TriangleExtra tr4 = new TriangleExtra(0, 5, 4);
            tr1.checkLegality(5, -5, 3);
        }   catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            throw ex;    
        } 

          System.out.println("Number of objects constructed: " +
            TriangleExtra.getNrOfObjects());
        }
}
```

It says "unhandled exception type". I don't understand what's happening?

What do I need to change, so that it only prints out (IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides side1 side2 and side3) without having to call the method xx.checkLegality on TryTriangleExtra?

I mean without this line  `tr1.checkLegality(5, -5, 3);`

How do I get only this output:

```
IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides 1000.0 1.0 and 1.0
IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides -5.0 5.0 and 5.0
IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides 0.0 5.0 and 4.0
Number of objects constructed: 4
```

With this try code:

```
public class TriangleExtraTry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TriangleExtra tr1 = new TriangleExtra(5);
            TriangleExtra tr2 = new TriangleExtra(1000, 1, 1);
            TriangleExtra tr3 = new TriangleExtra(-5, 5, 5);
            TriangleExtra tr4 = new TriangleExtra(0, 5, 4);
        }   catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            // something code    
        } 

          System.out.println("Number of objects constructed: " +
            TriangleExtra.getNrOfObjects());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

1. First would remove all the `try-catch` statements from the constructors of the `TriangleExtra` class. Once that is done, you can this statement in place of "// something code" in your class with the main method. Note that, with this approach, the main method's try-catch will complete with the exception thrown and will not process all the remaining constructor calls. But this is the right of using Exceptions since the constructors have the `throws` clause but you are actually handling the exception inside the constructor itself.

   ```
   System.out.println("IllegalTriangleException: " + ex.getMessage());
   ```
2. The second way would be to change the catch block inside every constructor and instead of doing `e.printstacktrace()`. If you are going to handle the exception in every constructor, then remove the `throws` clause fromall constructors and also remove the try-catch from the main method.

   ```
   } catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
       System.out.println("IllegalTriangleException: " + ex.getMessage());
   }
   ```

Try them out and select the one that suits your needs the best.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`System.out.println("IllegalTriangleException: " + ex.getMessage());`

I hope it helps :)

Comment: I put it in the last code where it now says "//something code". I still get same output.

Comment: Yeah I got it, in fact you obtain this result because in the `TriangleExtra` constructor 
you have a `try-catch` block where you print the exception stacktrace. The SudoRahul's answer covers this :)

Answer (score 0):

> It says "unhandled exception type". I don't understand what's happening?

NOTE: It says that because the code in the main throws an exception which is not handled. (putting `throw ex` does not handle the code, just throws it). for solving this you should remove the `throw ex`, or adding `throws IllegalTriangleException` to the main function stamp.

In order to print this:

```
IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides 1000.0 1.0 and 1.0
IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides -5.0 5.0 and 5.0
IllegalTriangleException: Invalid triangle with sides 0.0 5.0 and 4.0
Number of objects constructed: 4
```

you should do this:

```
    try {
        TriangleExtra tr1 = new TriangleExtra(5);
    }   catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
        System.out.println("IllegalTriangleException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        TriangleExtra tr2 = new TriangleExtra(1000, 1, 1);
    }   catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
        System.out.println("IllegalTriangleException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        TriangleExtra tr3 = new TriangleExtra(-5, 5, 5);
    }   catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
        System.out.println("IllegalTriangleException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        TriangleExtra tr4 = new TriangleExtra(0, 5, 4);
    }   catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
        System.out.println("IllegalTriangleException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Because when you write all the code in one block of `try`, after the first line of code, it throws an exception, and does not reach the other lines of code. If you want to create all the 4 triangles, with no dependent of each other, you should wrap each one with its own try-catch block